# Adding section to JSON output in ASP.net API core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using ASP.NET Core API to output a JSON array with using GET method.
The JSON structure is as following:

**Original:**

```
[{
    "Title": "My aswsome title_1",
    "ID": "1",
    "Settings": 32
},
{
    "Title": "My aswsome title_2",
    "ID": "2",
    "Settings": 33
}]
```

I looked over the web, but couldn't find how to add **Section** name to the whole JSON array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption here is that the original action returns just an array

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult MyAction() {
    Myitems[] array;

    //...array populate

    return Ok(array);
}
```

which produces the current result.

To wrap the array create an anonymous type

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult MyAction() {
    Myitems[] array;

    //...array populate

    return Ok(new { MyArraySection = array });
}
```

which will produce

```
{
  "MyArraySection" : [
    {
        "Title": "My aswsome title_1",
        "ID": "1",
        "Settings": 32
    },
    {
        "Title": "My aswsome title_2",
        "ID": "2",
        "Settings": 33
    }]
}
```